# Book involving a secret agent who travels back in time to the Bronze Age, along with Hercules and a Scythian girl

Tags: story-identification, books, time-travel, greek-myth, hercules

Looking for the title of a book I read in the late 90s.   A time traveling secret agent is sent back to the Bronze age seeking missing comrades.  He is met by a cabal of engineered Greek Gods who are apparently from the future as well. His traveling companions are Hercules himself and a Scythian girl.  From the story it might be part of a series.

Comment: The timeframe doesn't work but this feels like something in the Jason Thanou books by Steve White.

Answer (score 7):

Might his be *[Atlantis Found](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/263801.Atlantis_Found)* (1997) by R. Garcia Y. Robertson, the second book in the *[The Virgin and the Dinosaur](https://www.goodreads.com/series/132436-the-virgin-and-the-dinosaur)* duology...?

> In this sequel to "The Virgin and the Dinosaur", Jake Bento time travels in the Bronze Age, hoping to locate a lost time-traveling expedition. He is shocked to discover that his employers are masquerading as gods, enslaving the locals and pillaging art treasures. Abandoned in the Bronze Age by his employer, Jake has no alternative but to overthrow "the gods".

Comment: @Petrock - If anyone correctly identifies the book you're looking for, please mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons. Thanks.